# Python Selenium Click and Input Into Text Box

Tags: python, html, selenium

I am running Python 3.5 trying to "click" a text box with selenium so I can input rows of numbers. I have already scripted the login and navigation to the text box but I can't get my code to type "1234".

Here is the code, maybe there is something bigger in the HTML I am missing but the inspector tool shows the click box as below...

```
<td align="left" style="vertical-align: top;"><textarea
 class="stb-SearchBox" style="width: 100%; height: 5em;"
 dir=""></textarea></td>
```

I've tried the below and a few other different ways... maybe i'm missing something?

```
clickBox = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(class(), 'stb-SearchBox')]").click()

clickBox = driver.find_elements_by_class('stb-SearchBox').click()
```

eventually I will have my code use

```
clickBox.send_keys("1234")
```

Comment: First off `find_elements` returns a list and there is no xpath `class()` function, it would be `find_element_by_xpath("//*[@class='stb-SearchBox']")`

Answer (score 1):

```
//*[contains(class(), 'stb-SearchBox')]
```

Here you are incorrectly checking the `class` attribute. It needs to be `@class` instead of `class()`.

```
driver.find_elements_by_class('stb-SearchBox').click()
```

There is no `find_elements_by_class()` method available in Python `selenium` bindings. Use `find_element_by_class_name()` instead.

Or, you can use a simple *CSS selector* to locate the element:

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("textarea.stb-SearchBox")
```

Comment: Hmm it is still not working on selecting and inputting 1234...
I apologize if I made silly mistakes, I'm still pretty new to Python, Selenium Module, and the world of coding ;P

Comment: Figured it out a while back but thought i'd comment to bring this to a close. Just 'copying the xpath' instead of hunting for it. And annotating the xpath with ' instead of " made a big difference.